# Webpages stored in folder other than home are not opening on mobile

Tags: mobile, responsive

My website is running properly on the desktop/laptop
On mobile, it opens the home page correctly
But all other menu links do not open.
My understanding is that I have stored these pages in a folder inside home on the server
That is why, they are not opening.
How can I resolve this for mobile?